# "TWTRInvalidInitializationException" Twitter Login Crash app Ionic 4

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, twitter

I am Integration for Twitter Login in Ionic 4 Framework
I Follow [This link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/twitter-connect)  to integrate Twitter Login

i can able build successfully, but when i tap on twitter login button it crash with below error in xcode

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'TWTRInvalidInitializationException', reason: '[Twitter]
>   startWithConsumerKey:consumerSecret: called with empty consumer key or
>   secret.'

i also pass `ConsunerKey` and `ConsumerSecret` to `Info.plist` File but it didn't work

Below is my ionic files code:

in `app.module.ts` file

```
import { TwitterConnect } from '@ionic-native/twitter-connect/ngx';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    TwitterConnect,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

in `home.page.ts` file

```
import { TwitterConnect } from '@ionic-native/twitter-connect/ngx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private twitter: TwitterConnect) {}

  async doTwitterLogin() {
    this.twitter.login()
        .then(res => this.navCtrl.navigateForward('menunews'))
        .catch(err => this.navCtrl.navigateForward('social'));
  }
}
```

in home.page.html file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title text-center=true>
      Login
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-button expand="block" shape="round" (click)="doTwitterLogin()"> Twitter Login</ion-button>

</ion-content>
```

Can anybody work in ionic 4 twitter plugin?
what am i missing here any idea?